# How to read config file over HTTP in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration-files

I'd like to be able to do something like this (Python 3):

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('http://example.com/myconfig.cfg')
```

What is the best way to read a config file over HTTP in Python? I'm not married to `configparser` if there is a better option.

Comment: Just to make sure: be careful with loading external resources. They can post security risks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib2` to read file over HTTP and feed `config.readfp` with it.

```
import urllib2

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

r = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/myconfig.cfg")
config.readfp(r)
```

Comment: Note: This is Python 3, and assuming 3.2+, you'll want to use [`read_file`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file), not `readfp`. `readfp` has been deprecated since 3.2. Similarly, you'd want [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), not `urllib2.urlopen` for any Py3 version.

Comment: Using ShadowRanger's suggestions, I had to do:
config.read_string(r.read().decode('utf-8'))

urllib.request.urlopen returns a http.client.HTTPResponse object, so I had to do it that way, which works, does it look like the best way to do it?